# replace a whole line from a specific line to a specific line using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, command-line

I have done this code to replace a specific line to a specific line using sed:

```
i=5

while (( i <= 10 ))
        do
                sed -i '$i s/.*/change/' file.txt
                ((i++))
        done
```

and this is the file.txt

```
1.  alloha
2.  this
3.  is
4.  just
5.  a
6.  test
7.  nonsense
8.  words
9.  at
10. all
11. as
12. you
13. can
14. see
```

and after I run the script, file.txt change to this :

```
1.  alloha
2.  this
3.  is
4.  just
5.  a
6.  test
7.  nonsense
8.  words
9.  at
10. all
11. as
12. you
13. can
14. s/.*/change/
15. s/.*/change/
16. s/.*/change/
17. s/.*/change/
18. s/.*/change/
19. s/.*/change/
20. see
```

I believe that sed command works fine because I test it in the command line and it works as I want, I think the problem is just from the `i` variable.

so anyone know how to make this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I searched a little bit, I found that I must use double quotes `""` if I want to work with variables in sed command.

so instead of `''` I replaced it with this `""` as you can see in the following code :

```
i=5

while (( i <= 10 ))
do
    sed -i  "$i s/.*/change/" file.txt
    ((i++))
done
```

and now it works perfectly.
for more details click [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command).

Answer (score 0):

That seems to work for that simple use case but sed runs 5 times just to edit that file. Sed can do it in one invocation and does not involve looping while running sed 5 times!

```
sed -s '5,10s/\(^.*[[:space:]]\)*.*$/\1change/' file.txt
```